# How did the Sphere Builders build the Spheres?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

The [Sphere Builders](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sphere_Builder) couldn't exist in our dimension to build Spheres on their own. The [Xindi](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Xindi) were the Sphere Builders' only contact in our dimension. Also, the Xindi didn't know who built the Spheres, which means they didn't build them for the Sphere Builders.

How did the Sphere Builders really build the Spheres?

Comment: Don't try to trick us with your circular Sphere logic.

Comment: Spheres? In space? Don't tell [Space Sphere](http://theportalwiki.com/wiki/Core_voice_lines#Space_core)

Comment: Very carefully.

Comment: I always got the impression they were built in their dimension, then pushed into ours.

Comment: Enormous ice-cream-scoop-like devices.

Comment: BBlakes comment makes sense

Answer (score 8):

The Sphere Builders are capable of crossing over into our space (and have done so [at least once](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Harbinger_%28episode%29) to test the progress of the Spheres), so as suggested by @BBlake in the comments, the most likely possibilities seem to be:

- The Spheres were built in their dimension and pushed over to ours fully completed.
- The core of the Spheres were built in their dimension, and completed themselves in our dimension.  They do have [fairly sophisticated automated systems](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Anomaly_%28episode%29) and may have been able to do as such.

  - Similar to how they communicated with the Xindi, it's not necessarily even necessary for it to be automated.  The machines that built the Spheres could have been pushed over to our side, built the Spheres by remote control, and then been pulled back.

These are, however, just theories - but they're based entirely on things we've seen that the Sphere Builders are capable of.  Not much is known about their dimension, and I don't think how the Spheres were actually built was ever stated.

Comment: Looks like the only possible explanation... :)

Comment: Hold on a second... Haven't you thought about material existence compatiblity before pushing spheres to our dimension?

Comment: @SachinShekhar The pod in Harbinger existed just fine, so it seems to be a biological incompatibility

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that there's more a problem with their requirements for life sustainment than anything else. Because though the pod didn't suffer any ill effects in our space, once the Sphere Builder was removed, he degraded pretty quick.

Comment: How can you say that the pod was from their dimension?

Comment: The pod can be attached with sphere in the question...

Comment: @SachinShekhar Well, with regards to being made of the same material as the Spheres, as far as we know something from the Sphere Builders' dimension had to make it over to our side without disintegrating, either everything the Spheres are made of or the machine that built the Spheres over on our side.  So there certainly seems to be _something_ from their dimension that won't disintegrate in ours.  It's easiest to assume the pod was also from their dimension so that the Builder didn't have to spend time outside of it when he shifted over to our dimension - he just came over already in it.

Comment: You're thinking in classical way like they were shifting to another galaxy, not dimension. In the episode zero hour, their modified dimension was allowing them to insert their bodies to our machines. It means that that dimension was different because our dimension doesn't allow two objects to exist at same place.

Comment: Also perhaps they tricked/paid native species into building the spheres in our universe per the builder's specs.